# data transfer gird view to excel sheet

Tags: c#, asp.net

data transfer grid view to excel in asp dot net code is run but blank sheet generate of excel but data is not loaded in excel sheeet how to solve this type of broblem

```
protected void btnexcel_Click1(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

    Response.Clear();
    Response.Buffer = true;
    Response.AddHeader("content-disposition",  
    "attachment;filename=ActualsAndBudgets.xls");
    Response.Charset = "";
    Response.ContentType = "application/ms-excel";
    Response.Cache.SetCacheability(HttpCacheability.NoCache);
    StringWriter sw = new StringWriter();
    HtmlTextWriter htw = new HtmlTextWriter(sw);
    gvdetails.AllowPaging = false;
    gvdetails.DataBind();
    gvdetails.RenderControl(htw);
    Response.Write(sw.ToString());
    Response.End();

}
public override void VerifyRenderingInServerForm(Control control)
{

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Check for data in the gridview, your data is not getting binded. So the excel is empty. Debug and check for data inside the gridview. It should work.

Try with this one

```
    Response.Clear();
    Response.Buffer = true;
    Response.AddHeader("content-disposition",
    "attachment;filename=ActualsAndBudgets.xls");
    Response.Charset = "";
    Response.ContentType = "application/ms-excel";
    Response.Cache.SetCacheability(HttpCacheability.NoCache);
    StringWriter sw = new StringWriter();
    HtmlTextWriter htw = new HtmlTextWriter(sw);
    GridView1.RenderControl(htw);
    Response.Write(sw.ToString());
    Response.End();
```

Comment: Show Error          ----->    RegisterForEventValidation can only be called during Render();

Comment: Set EventValidation to false for the page and also override VerifyRenderingInServerForm in code behind,

Comment: public override void VerifyRenderingInServerForm(Control control)
{
 
}

Answer (score 0):

may be problem in data binding in export excel .
check that data properly bin to a gridview or not.

Use this code for export grid view in excel sheet and note that you must add iTextSharp dll in you project.

```
 protected void btnExportExcel_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Response.Clear();
        Response.Buffer = true;
        Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment;filename=GridViewExport.xls");
        Response.Charset = "";
        Response.ContentType = "application/vnd.ms-excel";

        StringWriter sw = new StringWriter();
        HtmlTextWriter hw = new HtmlTextWriter(sw);
        GridView1.AllowPaging = false;

        // Re-Bind data to GridView 

        using (CompMSEntities1 CompObj = new CompMSEntities1())
        {
            Start = Convert.ToDateTime(txtStart.Text);
            End = Convert.ToDateTime(txtEnd.Text);

            GridViewSummaryReportCategory.DataSource = CompObj.SP_Category_Summary(Start, End);
            SP_Category_Summary_Result obj1 = new SP_Category_Summary_Result();
            GridView1.DataBind();
           GridView1.Visible = true;
            ExportTable.Visible = true;
        }

        //Change the Header Row back to white color

        GridView1.HeaderRow.Style.Add("background-color", "#FFFFFF");


       GridView1.Style.Add(" font-size", "10px");




        //Apply style to Individual Cells

        GridView1.HeaderRow.Cells[0].Style.Add("background-color", "green");
        GGridView1.HeaderRow.Cells[1].Style.Add("background-color", "green");
        GridView1.HeaderRow.Cells[2].Style.Add("background-color", "green");
        GridView1.HeaderRow.Cells[3].Style.Add("background-color", "green");
        GridView1.HeaderRow.Cells[4].Style.Add("background-color", "green");

        for (int i = 1; i < GridView1.Rows.Count; i++)
        {
            GridViewRow row = GridView1.Rows[i];

            //Change Color back to white

            row.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.White;

            //Apply text style to each Row

        //    row.Attributes.Add("class", "textmode");

            //Apply style to Individual Cells of Alternating Row

            if (i % 2 != 0)
            {
                row.Cells[0].Style.Add("background-color", "#C2D69B");
                row.Cells[1].Style.Add("background-color", "#C2D69B");
                row.Cells[2].Style.Add("background-color", "#C2D69B");
                row.Cells[3].Style.Add("background-color", "#C2D69B");
                row.Cells[4].Style.Add("background-color", "#C2D69B");
            }
        }
        GridView1.RenderControl(hw);

        //style to format numbers to string

        string style = @"<style> .textmode { mso-number-format:\@; } </style>";

        Response.Write(style);
        Response.Output.Write(sw.ToString());
        Response.Flush();
        Response.End();
    }
```